# Using parent class object to instantiate a child class object in Scala?

Tags: scala

For example, there are two scala class called A and B.

```
class A{
  val aVariable:String="a"
}

class B(val newVariable:String) extends A{
  def newMethod(): Unit ={

  }
}
```

The problem is how to use an A object to instantiate a B object with its variable?
For example, a function take an A object and a string to create a B object

```
val bObject:B=BuildFunc(new A(),"string")
```

And if A contains much variables, is there a way to avoid setting each of manually?

It seems in Java this could be done by code like `super(aObject)`, is there equivalent method in Scala?

Comment: scala classes are really for java interoperability, so whatever you can do on java classes, you can also do on scala classes. However, the `super` method you mention does not work the way you want. It is used to make a constructor for `B` using a constructor for `A`, which you can do in scala doing `class B(aParam, bParam) extends A(aParam)`.

Answer (score 0):

There's multiple solutions here. For example, one would be defining A's promoting the A's constructor parameters into fields:

```scala
class A(val foo: String)
class B(override val foo: String, val baz: String) extends A(foo)
```

If you can't change A's definition though then maybe this will help:

```scala
class A {
  val foo: String = "foo"
}
class B(override val foo: String, val baz: String) extends A
```

Hope that helps.